# Python errors out in Powershell ISE

Tags: python, powershell, powershell-ise

I am at Chapter One of Zed Shaw's Python the Hard Way book and I'm already stuck. I can run python in a command shell, but when I try to run it in PowerShell, I get this:

```
python : Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Python 3.7.3 (v...ntel)] on win32:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Any guidance appreciated. I'm going to move on using the command shell for now but would love to figure out PowerShell

Comment: Is python on your `PATH` in your system environment variables? And you are just trying to enter `python` as a command into powershell and nothing else?

Answer (score 4):

You have to run **Windows PowerShell**, and not Windows PowerShell **ISE**.

The **ISE** is a script editor for PowerShell, and doesn't run python. Windows PowerShell (not ISE) does allow you to run python.

Comment: Great sleuthing; alternatively, run from a PowerShell _Core_ console window.

Comment: Interesting that the ISE won't run it while the console will. I wonder if launching the ISE with the -MTA parameter will allow it to run Python.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: That doesn't seem to make a difference; in fact, if you try to run `cmd.exe`, you'll get `Cannot start "cmd". Interactive console applications are not supported`. Trying to run `python` should yield the same error, but doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Interactive console applications are not supported in ISE, use PowerShell instead.

[Console Application (Non) Support in the ISE](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/console-application-non-support-in-the-ise/)